# How can I access bpy on anaconda (win 10 x64)

Tags: python, anaconda, blender

I'd like to convert an (x, y, z) coordinate to a mesh vertex in anaconda.

Here's the code I'd like to run on Anaconda:

```
import bpy
vertices=[(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,1)]
Faces=[(0,1,2,3)]
EasyMeshVariable=bpy.data.meshes.new("MeshName")
EasyObjectVariable=bpy.data.objects.new("ObjectName",EasyMeshVariable)
EasyObjectVariable.location = bpy.context.scene.cursor_location
bpy.context.scene.objects.link(EasyObjectVariable)
EasyMeshVariable.from_pydata(Vertices,[],Faces)
```

But I got the following error.

```
ModuleNotFoundError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-575093cfaedd> in <module>()
----> 1 import bpy
      2 vertices=[(0,0,0),(0,1,0),(1,0,0),(1,1,1)]
      3 Faces=[(0,1,2,3)]
      4 EasyMeshVariable=bpy.data.meshes.new("MeshName")
      5 
    EasyObjectVariable=bpy.data.objects.new("ObjectName",EasyMeshVariable)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy'
```

Does anyone know how to install bpy on Anaconda (Windows 10 x64)?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you able to add a code example of the problem, to better help people understand the problem?

Comment: What problem you're trying to solve? `bpy` is available to scripts running inside blender, or as standalone module, which as I'm aware is not part of blender installation and have to be built manually.

Comment: I'm trying to use bpy command in python or anaconda.

Comment: As you show no intention of describing your problem, the only answer is "build module yourself", "run it in blender instead", or not at all. Let's assume you can import said module - then what? What is your problem that you think it will help you with? If problem is so specific to blender features, running blender script is the most logical solution.

Comment: Hi Keltar, I'm sorry to let you feel I show no intention of describing my problem. Actually, I reedit my post to try to describe my question better. I though it might be more clear, but I was wrong. Why I want to know how to run it on anaconda cause I processed  images on anaconda too. And I'm wondering if it's possible to access bpy on anaconda and I don't need to switch between anaconda and blender. Thanks for your answers. You're right. It's better to run blender script. I also saw some posts indicated that the blander used python code. Why I'm persistent to run it in anaconda?! Thanks.

Comment: You need to [build blender as a python module](https://en.blender.org/index.php/User:Ideasman42/BlenderAsPyModule)